# Javascript multiple keys to the same value - Do they point to the same place?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have the following simplified code:

```
var obj = {
    key1 : {
            aliases: ["alias1", "alias2"],
            prop1: someVal,
            prop2: someOtherVal
        }
}
var objHashMap = {};
for(var key in obj){
    objHashMap[key] = obj[key];
    objHashMap[obj[key].aliases[0]] = obj[key];
    objHashMap[obj[key].aliases[1]] = obj[key];
}
```

Now `objHashMap` has 3 entries, and all entries points at:

```
{
        aliases: ["alias1", "alias2"],
        prop1: someVal,
        prop2: someOtherVal
}
```

My question is weather all 3 points to the same object, or points to 3 different copies of the object?

Comment: Since `obj[key]` is an object, they all will reference to the same object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`objHashMap.key1` will have a *copy* of the *value* in `obj.key`. That value is a reference to an object. Both copies of that value refer to the same object. The you use the value of `obj.key1.aliases[0]` and `obj.key1.aliases[1]` to create two additional properties which *also* have copies of the reference, referring to the same object.

After this:

```
var obj = {
    key1 : {
            aliases: ["alias1", "alias2"],
            prop1: someVal,
            prop2: someOtherVal
        }
}
```

...we have this in memory:

```
                +----------------+
obj: ref-1654-->|    (object)    |
                +----------------+     +-------------------+
                | key1: ref-8754 |---->|     (object)      |
                +----------------+     +-------------------+     +-------------+
                                       | aliases: ref-6549 |---->|  (array)    |
                                       | prop1: ???        |     +-------------+
                                       | prop2: ???        |     | 0: "alias1" |
                                       +-------------------+     | 1: "alias2" |
                                                                 +-------------+
```

That is, we have a variable, `obj`, which contains a value that tells the JavaScript engine where an object is elsewhere in memory; I've shown that as `ref-1654` above. Think of an object reference as a number that has meaning only to the JavaScript engine, like an index into a big array of memory. (The actual value of an object reference is something we never see.)

That object has a property, `key1`, which again has a value pointing to an object elsewhere in memory. That object, in turn, has `aliases` with *another* reference to an object (this time an array) in memory. The values of `prop1` and `prop2` in the object with `aliases` are unknown (they come from the variables `someVal` and `someOtherVal`, which you haven't defined for us).

Then this line adds another variable pointing to another object:

```
var objHashMap = {};
```

```
                       +----------------+
objHashMap: ref-8132-->|    (object)    |
                       +----------------+
                       |                |
                       +----------------+
```

Your `for-in` loop only runs once, for the key `"key1"`. After the first line:

```
objHashMap[key] = obj[key];
```

we have:

```
                +----------------+
obj: ref-1654-->|    (object)    |
                +----------------+          
                | key1: ref-8754 |---------+
                +----------------+         |
                                           |
                                           |
                                           |   +-------------------+                 
                                           +-->|     (object)      |                 
                                           |   +-------------------+     +-------------+
                                           |   | aliases: ref-6549 |---->|  (array)    |
                       +----------------+  |   | prop1: ???        |     +-------------+
objHashMap: ref-8132-->|    (object)    |  |   | prop2: ???        |     | 0: "alias1" |
                       +----------------+  |   +-------------------+     | 1: "alias2" |
                       | key1: ref-8754 |--+                             +-------------+
                       +----------------+
```

Note how the `key1` property in the new object contains the *same value* as the `key1` property in the original object. They point to the same object.

Then you do:

```
objHashMap[obj[key].aliases[0]] = obj[key];
```

...which is to say

```
objHashMap[obj.key1.aliases[0]] = obj[key];
```

...since `key` contains `"key1"`, which is to say

```
objHashMap["alias1"] = obj[key];
```

...because `obj.key1.aliases[0]` is `"alias1"`. That gives us:

```
                +----------------+
obj: ref-1654-->|    (object)    |
                +----------------+          
                | key1: ref-8754 |-----------+
                +----------------+           |
                                             |
                                             |
                                             |    +-------------------+                 
                                             ++-->|     (object)      |                 
                                             ||   +-------------------+     +-------------+
                                             ||   | aliases: ref-6549 |---->|  (array)    |
                       +------------------+  ||   | prop1: ???        |     +-------------+
objHashMap: ref-8132-->|     (object)     |  ||   | prop2: ???        |     | 0: "alias1" |
                       +------------------+  ||   +-------------------+     | 1: "alias2" |
                       | key1:   ref-8754 |--+|                             +-------------+
                       | alias1: ref-8754 |---+ 
                       +------------------+
```

Then again for this line:

```
objHashMap[obj[key].aliases[1]] = obj[key];
```

...which is:

```
objHashMap["alias2"] = obj[key];
```

...because `obj.key1.aliases[1]` is `"alias2"`. So we end up with:

```
                +----------------+
obj: ref-1654-->|    (object)    |
                +----------------+          
                | key1: ref-8754 |-----------+
                +----------------+           |
                                             |
                                             |
                                             |    +-------------------+                 
                                             +++->|     (object)      |                 
                                             |||  +-------------------+     +-------------+
                                             |||  | aliases: ref-6549 |---->|  (array)    |
                       +------------------+  |||  | prop1: ???        |     +-------------+
objHashMap: ref-8132-->|     (object)     |  |||  | prop2: ???        |     | 0: "alias1" |
                       +------------------+  |||  +-------------------+     | 1: "alias2" |
                       | key1:   ref-8754 |--+||                            +-------------+
                       | alias1: ref-8754 |---+|
                       | alias2: ref-8754 |----+ 
                       +------------------+
```

Comment: I really like the ASCII schemes T.J.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these point to the same object. Let me take an example to demonstrate the same:

```
  var obj = {
      key1 : {
              aliases: [1,2],
              prop1: 3,
              prop2: 4
          }
  }
  //initialize another object which will contain the same values.
  var objHashMap = {};
  for(var key in obj){
      objHashMap[key] = obj[key];
      objHashMap[obj[key].aliases[0]] = obj[key];
      objHashMap[obj[key].aliases[1]] = obj[key];
  }
  //change the value of a key in objHashMap.
  objHashMap["key1"].prop1 = 600
  //now observe the value changed in other keys as well.
  console.log(objHashMap[1].prop1);
  console.log(objHashMap[2].prop1);
  console.log(obj);
```